# Include a jquery.tmpl template for knockout.js?

Tags: knockout.js, jquery-templates

Silly question, maybe, but I can't find a documented answer anywhere.

I'm trying to save a jquery tmpl template, and include it as a script. Seems like this should work:

```
<script src="my_tmpl.js" type="text/javascript" id="myTemplate"></script>
```

But no luck. What am I doing wrong?

Just for completeness' sake, here's the kind of binding I'm doing for knockout:

```
<div id="myTemplatedBox" data-bind="template: 'myTemplate'">
```

Edit: Here's a very reduced version of the my_tmpl.js contents.  It works fine when I keep it in the main html document.

```
    <div class="headerText">{{html header_text}}</div>
    {{each(i,v) answer_array}}
        <div class="questionText"><input type="radio" name="Q${i}" value="${i+1}">{{html v}}</input></div>
    {{/each}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at http://encosia.com/jquery-templates-composite-rendering-and-remote-loading/

It looks like you still need the script tag in your template file.

```
<script id="invoiceTemplate" type="x-jquery-tmpl"> 
  <div class="questionBox">
      <div class="headerText">{{html header_text}}</div>
      {{each(i,v) answer_array}}
          <div class="questionText"><input type="radio" name="Q${i}" value="${i+1}">{{html v}}</input></div>
      {{/each}}
  </div>
</script>
```

Comment: Good link -- I see how this could work. But it seems like overkill. Is there any way to include the template without all the asychronous $.get syntax?

Comment: I guess I'll bow to the inevitable. I suppose the AJAXy way really isn't that bad.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change the type to **text\html** and give it another go:

```
<script src="my_tmpl.js" type="text/html" id="myTemplate"></script>
```

Comment: What is inside you my_tmpl.js file? Could you post the contents.

Comment: I've added it to the question.